# PowerShell script doesn't work when executed by PHP

Tags: php, powershell, shell-exec

I created a PowerShell script designed to be executed by PHP using `shell_exec()`.

The PowerShell script is:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
$process=Get-Process "cmd" | where {$_.mainWindowTitle -like "*FTB*"}
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate($process.ID)
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("whitelist reload{ENTER}")
```

And the PHP execution line is:

```
$out = shell_exec("powershell C:\whitelist_reload.ps1");
echo ($out);
```

The script executes, and I am given return information through the `Echo`. It it saying that the `$process` variable assigned to the value of `Get-Process` in Line 3 of the PS script is empty. The issue lies in that if I execute the script manually through a PowerShell executable, the script executes perfectly, and does exactly what I want.

---

Is there a particular reason why Line 3 returns nothing when executed by PHP, yet works fully when executed in PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely [Session 0 isolation](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/archive/b/developers/archive/2009/10/01/session-0-isolation.aspx) . `CMD` is running in a user session, while php(or the web server) is running as a service. Services in Windows 7 runs in an isolated session called `Session 0`. Processes in this session cannot communicate with other processes.

So you `Get-process` command can't list your `CMD`-process because it doesn't have access to it. You can verify the isolation by running `$process=Get-Process "cmd"` and echoing the results. I've never tried it, but I'm pretty sure you won't find any processes that you run interactively.

Comment: Sounds like that's the issue. I wonder if there's a way around it, like starting up a cmd window first, and then executing the script through that window with batch.